# How to create a .BAT file to download file from HTTP\ftp server?

Tags: windows, ftp, batch-file

How to create a `.BAT` file to download file or folder from FTP server? (and replace with it existing file) (we have links like `ftp://me:mypass@example.com/file.file` (or http://example.com/file.file) and absolute file link like `C:\Users\UserName\Some mixed Русский English Adress\file.file`) (using only native windows (xp vista win7 etc) BAT functions and files)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of how to automate the built-in `ftp.exe` tool:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/

The example is about uploading, but the principle is the same (just use `get` instead of `put`).

Still, since this is just "piping commands" into ftp.exe, I recommend not to do this for production-quality batch files (no error handling, etc.), but to use some external tool instead. I provided this answer only because you explicitly asked for a solution that only uses Windows built-in commands.

EDIT: Here's a concrete example:

```
REM replace this with your user name and password
REM make sure there is no space between the pwd and the >>

echo user me > getftp.dat
echo mypass>> getftp.dat

echo binary >> getftp.dat

REM replace this with the remote dir (or remove, if not required)

echo cd remoteSubDir >> getftp.dat

REM replace this with the local dir

echo lcd C:\Users\UserName\SomeLocalSubDir >> getftp.dat

REM replace this with the file name

echo get file.file >> getftp.dat
echo quit >> getftp.dat

REM replace this with the server name

ftp -n -s:getftp.dat example.com

del getftp.dat
```

Comment: So... grate how to replace existing file with recived file? Could you add code example, please.

Comment: I am in a situation where I need to copy a file from an FTP path to a local folder in my machine. How Can I achieve that using batch file.

Comment: @ch.smrutiranjanparida: That's exactly what the example in my answer does.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously used WGET in a batch file to accomplish this.
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Answer (score 1):

What FTP client software are you using?  Is it scriptable?  If so, create a script that downloads files and call this script from your batch file.

I'm doing this with WS_FTP.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line FTP program that's built-in to most Windows operating systems [is scriptable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269). You just need to create a text file with the commands you would send if you were running it by hand (one command per line), then execute it like this:

```
ftp -s:download.scr
```

Comment: So... grate how to replace  existing file with recived file? Could you add code example, please.