# Bat File FTP Commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am attempting to download a file via FTP in a batch file. The solution is very similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866787/how-to-create-a-bat-file-to-download-file-from-http-ftp-server). The only difference is that I'm getting an error of "501 Server Cannot Accept Argument".

Here is the code of my bat file:

```
@echo off
echo user removed> ftpcmd.dat
echo removed>> ftpcmd.dat
echo CD /removed.com/assets/csv/>> ftpcmd.dat
echo LCD C:\Temp >> ftpcmd.dat
echo TYPE>> ftpcmd.dat
echo GET valid_file.php new.php>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat removed.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Here is the output of my bat file running:

```
c:\Temp>test
Connected to removed.com.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
ftp> user removed
331 Password required for removed.

230 User logged in.
ftp> CD /removed.com/assets/csv/
250 CWD command successful.
ftp> LCD C:\Temp
Local directory now c:\Temp.
ftp> TYPE
Using ascii mode to transfer files.
ftp> GET valid_file.php new.php
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

Comment: try GET valid_file.php >> ftpcmd.dat

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 MGET valid_file.php new.php >> ftpcmd.dat
```

leave the new.php or do that later.

UNless of course is a network error, in which case you need to add the proper ports.

Comment: you think it could be a network issue? is it using default port 20/21 for FTP?

Comment: try manually going into terminal and typing out the script commands sans the >> outputs.

Comment: also try putting a dummy text file on the server without any funky characters. Just text. And see if you can do a get command. the PHP might have something weird in it that's tripping the server up.

Comment: Using the same commands directly in the command line has the same result.

Comment: Same goes for an empty txt file on the server.

Comment: maybe we should try using binary mode instead of ascii

Comment: also for multiple files mget may be your answer

Comment: if none of these work it's the FTP firewall settings in IIS. You have to specifically allow for passive mode. Here is a link: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings-in-iis-7

Comment: @CoryDee: I may be wrong but your question seems to be turning into either a [sf] or [su] one.